# GAT: RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float

Tags: networking, graph, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to build a GAT model by taking 1 graph at a time from a dataset of 400 graphs
I want to predict node features later on...

I am getting following error:

```
torch_geometric/nn/dense/linear.py", line 130, in forward
    return F.linear(x, self.weight, self.bias)
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float
```

Following is my code,
Here, x and y are 40-by-1 tensors, while edge_feature and and edge_attr are 2-by-number_of_edges.
In x I have unicode values at indexes where nodes are present, and 0 at indexes where nodes are absent. y is a cut down version of x, some node values are replaced by 0.

```
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

        self.Input_Dim = None  # Initialize Input_Dim
        self.Output_Dim = None  # Initialize Output_Dim

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        print(f"Processing sample at index {idx}")
        complex_data = self.data[idx]
  
        # My data processing ...

        data = Data(x=combined_labels_trans, edge_index=Edge_Index_Tensor, edge_attr=Edge_Feature_Tensor, y=pep_trans)
        
        return data

dataset = CustomDataset(data)

train_complexes, val_complexes = train_test_split(list(range(len(dataset))), test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
print("Training complexes:", train_complexes)
print("Validation complexes:", val_complexes)
train_data = [dataset[i] for i in train_complexes]
val_data = [dataset[i] for i in val_complexes]


def custom_collate_geometric(data_list):
    return Batch.from_data_list(data_list)
     
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=True, collate_fn=custom_collate_geometric)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_data, batch_size=1, collate_fn=custom_collate_geometric)


class GATModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_heads):
        super(GATModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = GATConv(input_dim, hidden_dim, heads=num_heads)
        self.conv2 = GATConv(hidden_dim * num_heads, output_dim, heads=num_heads)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(output_dim * num_heads, output_dim)

    def forward(self, data):
        x, edge_index, edge_attr = data.x, data.edge_index, data.edge_attr  
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)  
        x = F.elu(x)  
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)  
        x = F.elu(x)  
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = F.elu(x) 
        return x


input_dim = 1  
output_dim = 1  
hidden_dim = 64
num_heads = 4  

model = GATModel(input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, num_heads)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0.0
    for batch in tqdm(train_loader, desc=f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}"):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(batch)
        outputs = outputs.squeeze()
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch.y.squeeze().long())
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs} - Loss: {running_loss / len(train_loader)}")

model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    val_loss = 0.0
    for batch in val_loader:
        outputs = model(batch)
        outputs = outputs.squeeze()
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch.y.squeeze().long())
        val_loss += loss.item()
    print(f"Validation Loss: {val_loss / len(val_loader)}")

torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'gat_model.pth')
```